# eledmac \boxlinenum and \numberonlyfirstinline

Tags: endnotes, eledmac

I need to follow a pre-existing layout, which went smoothly so far. Only a few questions are still open. One is: I use boxlinenum to put a box around the linenumber. but if the linenumber is repeated i want to have an empty space. That does not work:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{eledmac}

\firstlinenum{0} \linenumincrement{1}
\boxlinenum{8mm}
\numberonlyfirstinline[A]
\inplaceofnumber[A]{2cm}

\begin{document}
      \beginnumbering\pstart
\edtext{What}{\Afootnote{Whit}} a \edtext{piece}{\Afootnote{peace}} of work is man! how noble in reason! 
         \pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

By the way: Can i use boxlinenum for endnotes as well? I don't seem to manage.

Comment: you should ask one question in same time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a bug. I have corrected it in the branch which I will release on CTAN next week.

Add `\symlinenum{}` before my correction to have a correct way.

Also open an issue on github for the boxlinenum for endnotes.

Comment: you'r welcome. Don't forget to validate the answer (for StackExchange operation) and to open an issue on github for your question about endnotes (yet, there is now easy way)